# Scattering Matrix and the Lippmann-Schwinger equation in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I am currently studying scattering theory from the Sakurai's quantum mechanics. I have previously studied this subject from Griffith's quantum mechanics. In the latter textbook, scattering matrices for one-dimensional problems were discussed by solving the Schrodinger equation and taking ratio of amplitudes to determine the $S$-matrix. In Sakurai's book, scattering theory is introduced by discussing the [Lippmann-Schwinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation). The solutions to this equation are the forward and backward scattering states $\psi^{(+)}$ and $\psi^{(-)}$.

I have calculated these states for the 1D delta function potential and compared them to the results from Griffiths discussion on 1D scattering; both results agree. **However, is there a formula that relates the $S$-matrix elements and these states $\psi^{(+)}$ and $\psi^{(-)}$?**

Comment: There's a section on the wikipedia article you linked to called [A formula for the S-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippmann%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation#A_formula_for_the_S-matrix) that has what you want :)

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **However, is there a formula that relates the S-matrix elements and these states $\psi^{(+)}$ and $\psi^{(-)}$?**

You have not provided a sufficiently detailed description of what exactly the $\psi^{(+)}$ and $\psi^{(-)}$ functions are, and I do not have a copy of Sakurai to look at to supplement the minimal description provided here.

So, I will proceed by making some assumptions. I will assume that
$$
\psi^{(\pm)}_\alpha = \Omega^{(\pm)}\phi_\alpha\;,\tag{1}
$$
where $\Omega^{(\pm)}$ are Moller wave operators, as discussed further, for example, in [Joachain's "Quantum Collision Theory"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444867732) at chapter 14.

The function
$$
\psi^{(\pm)}_\alpha
$$
is an eigenfunction of the full Hamiltonian $H$, including the scattering potential $V$.

The function
$$
\phi_\alpha
$$
is an eigenfunction of the (hopefully simpler) "unperturbed" Hamiltonian $H_0 = H-V$.

The index $\alpha$ on each of the two above functions represents a collection of numbers defining the state of the system and we have
$$
H_0 \phi_\alpha = E_\alpha \phi_\alpha\;.
$$

We can also write Eq. (1) a little more concretely as:
$$
\psi^{(\pm)}_\alpha = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\pm i\epsilon}{E_\alpha - H \pm i\epsilon}\phi_\alpha \tag{2}\;.
$$
$$
=\phi_\alpha + \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{E_\alpha - H \pm i\epsilon}V\phi_\alpha
$$

The $S$ matrix is given by:
$$
S_{\beta,\alpha} = \langle \phi_\beta|S|\phi_\alpha\rangle
$$
$$
=\langle \phi_\beta|{\Omega^{(-)}}^{\dagger}\Omega^{(+)}|\phi_\alpha\rangle
$$
$$
=\langle \psi^{-}_\beta|\psi^{+}_\alpha\rangle \;,
$$
which provides a simple expression for the $S$ matrix in terms of the $\psi$ states.